# List Items not displaying in this Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

Exception is : **Resources.NotFoundException**

11-30 17:38:17.843: I/class fyp.proj.crud.DisplayProjects$ListAdapter(967): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9

Firstly, I've looked at several answers already, but this seems a little more specific.

I'm having real difficulty tracking the problem with a ListAdapter, the items dont display anything I know an exception is being thrown, because its being caught and I'm attempting to log it - however all the log says is

11-30 15:33:06.703: I/class fyp.proj.crud.DisplayPlacements$ListAdapter(400): String resource ID #0x7

the values I'm trying to put into the listitem are set, the rather crude sys.err proves this. it is also worth noting that the number of items in the list expands when I insert or delete data, its just not visible

code below.

```
/* ListAdapter */
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Placement> {
private ArrayList<Placement> mList;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    ArrayList<Placement> list) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
    this.mList = list;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    try {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    final Placement p = mList.get(position);
    if (p != null) {

        // setting list_item views

        /* some error in here means that the items aren't being set */
        System.err.println(p.getTitle() + " "
            + p.getId());
        /*
         * this sys.err gets the details sucessfully from the
         * placement object
         */

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id)).setText(p
            .getId());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)).setText(p
            .getTitle());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc)).setText(p
            .getDesc());
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(DisplayProjects.ListAdapter.class.toString(),
        e.getMessage());
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Try e.printStackTrace() instead of getMessage(), than you will se the error Message on Logcat.

Comment: used Log.i(DisplayProjects.ListAdapter.class.toString(),
   Log.getStackTraceString(e)); to acheive this, turns out its a resource not found error.

Comment: @Thommy it turns out the textviews aren't being found, any ideas where to look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line could be the problem:

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id)).setText(p.getId());
```

if getId is not returning a String the number is meant as resource id. Try:

```
...setText(String.valueOf(p.getId()));
```

Comment: Good shout but p.getId() returns a string.

Comment: Actually it wasn't returning a string. Great shout!